# Fail to insert data to cloned SQL Tables

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

I have two databases that I am updating via Powershell leveraging trusted connections. The two databases are marked as Database_PRD, and Database_DEV respectively. Recently the _DEV database is not getting updated for some strange reason. The databases live on the same server and presumably use the same trusted connection to connect.

I ran a simple invoke query and update command and it seems to work against the two databases on the same server. However when I run the powershell script to update the two databases it fails on _DEV completely all the time. Having a hard time figuring out why when _DV is a clone of _PRD

Comment: You are going to gave to supply a lot more information than that before anyone can help you. As a start, please tag your question with the DBMS you are using and edit your question to include the powershell script

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Recloned PRIMARY db as New db, and it seemed to have resolved the problem. To this day we don't know why one DB was able to be updated vs. a copy of it (as secondary). Must have been a tiny difference we did not pick up.